# Using Java `CompletablyFuture.exceptionally` to optionally continue through exceptions

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, completable-future

I have a series of asynchronous tasks chained together using Java `CompletableFutures`. The code looks something like this:

```
CompletableFuture<Result> doTasks(final TaskId id) {
    return firstTask.workAsync(id)
            .thenComposeAsync(__ -> secondTask.workAsync(id))
            .thenComposeAsync(__ -> thirdTask.workAsync(id))
            .thenApplyAsync(__ -> fourthTask.workAsync(id));
}
```

However, `firstTask.workAsync` throws an exception indicating that the work has already been completed, which is OK in this situation, so I would like to just ignore it and continue through the chain.

Of course, I could just wrap that bit in a separate function where I can handle the exception, but is there a way to handle it directly in the `CompletableFuture` chain and continue to throw all other exceptions?

A co-worker suggested I use `CompletableFuture.exceptionally`, but all of the examples online that I see are totally useless and just return null, which looks like it would kill the chain. How would I use that in this case?

Answer (score 0):

[CompletableFuture.exceptionally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#exceptionally-java.util.function.Function-) can be used to continue when getting an exception in a `CompletableFuture`. In a nutshell, you need to check the type of the exception, and if it's an exception you want to continue on, you can return a new `CompletableFuture`, which can be empty since the result is not used down the chain.

```
CompletableFuture<Result> doTasks(final TaskId id) {
    return firstTask.workAsync(id)
            .exceptionally(t -> {
                // Will continue down the chain if matches
                if (t instanceof TotallyOkException) {
                    return null;
                }

                // This will throw an ExecutionException. I convert it to a RuntimeException here 
                // because I don't want to add throws statements up the chain.
                throw new RuntimeException(t);
            })
            .thenComposeAsync(__ -> secondTask.workAsync(id))
            .thenComposeAsync(__ -> thirdTask.workAsync(id))
            .thenApplyAsync(__ -> fourthTask.workAsync(id));
}
```

In this case, it will throw all non-`TotallyOkException` exceptions.

Comment: I presume you mean `return null` rather than `return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null)`?

Comment: @JoeC Won't returning null kill the chain? It works as expected as is, but if I want tasks 2-4 to still run, won't I need to return a CompletableFuture?

Comment: This is the signature: `exceptionally(Function<Throwable,? extends T> fn)`.  So this will only work if you have a `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<T>>`.  There is no reason that returning `null` should stop the chain.

Comment: @JoeC I gotcha. I switched it to return `null`, and it still works as expected, so you're right. I updated the answer accordingly. Tx.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `null` in your `exceptionally` function will not, in itself, kill the chain.  The only way it will kill the chain is a result of lack of null handling in the downstream function and causing a `NullPointerException`.

Your `exceptionally` function can be set up to handle some types of exception and not others.  For example:

```
return firstTask.workAsync(id)
        .thenComposeAsync(firstResult -> secondTask.workAsync(id))
        .exceptionally(t -> {
                           if (t instanceof TransientException) {
                               return getUsingBackupMethod(id);
                           }
                           throw new RuntimeException(t);
                       });
```

This `exceptionally` function will (effectively) catch an exception thrown from either of the first two tasks.